# FragmentManager incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter super constructor

Tags: android

I am following the Android [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). Trying to learn how to use a ViewPager. The problem i am running into is that i am not able to pass the `FragmentManager` i obtain from `Activity` to my custom adapter that extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Here is some code.

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

and the adapter snippet.

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
```

I can see the issue is mainly because `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is in `support.v4` and its expecting a `support.v4` version of the FragmentManager. So how do i proceed?

Comment: u have to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: k dude..have a nice day.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JaredBurrows read comment from `Flash`

Comment: @DevZer0 Ok, so post the solution and mark it correct. This is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

@Flash answered this correctly in the comments, but in case others are searching for an answer, the OP needs to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: that doesn't look like an answer. you need to at least put a code-sample and write something pretty :) then i will accept it :)

Comment: Ok.. it is solved now. I didn't change getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager().